# Update value / item for combobox after selecting datagrid item

Tags: c#, binding, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I have been looking on the internet for a solution of the problem I have.
Basically I want to select an item on a datagrid and that should update a few textboxes (not a problem) and a combobox (a nightmare)

Please see a code snippet for the combobox (& textboxes) below :

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedStudy.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModalityTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="ModalityTypeCode" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=_studyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Modality, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Modality" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedStudy.Duration, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

My Datagrid :

```
 <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="_studyDataGrid"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Studies, Mode=OneWay}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudy, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Margin=" 5,5,5,5"
                  >
```

The above code doesn't work, meaning whenever I click a row in the datagrid, the combobox doesn't get updated.

I also tried:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModalityTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="ModalityTypeCode" 
           SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=_studyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Modality, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Modality" />
```

I'm lost, any ideas?

Regards,

Erik

Comment: Does the "SelectedItem have a valid "ModalityType"? If so you should be able to bind like this.  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModalityTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="ModalityTypeCode" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Modality, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: No it has not, modalitytypes is a different list than the selecteditem which comes from a list Studies, but the values are the same. Meaning there can never be a study with a non-existent modalitytype

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean you want the selected value of the ComboBox to display dataGrid.
It is enough to ComboBox.SelectedValue =Cint( DataGrid.SelectedItems.Item(0).FieldName) to add.
this Code Add To DataGrid Selection Changed Event.
Good luck

Comment: No, I want it exactly the other way around. I want to select an item from the datagrid and then the combobox should be populated with the datagrid.selecteditem. I'm using MVVM, so I would rather not use the code behind file.